# access method outside vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i am new in vuejs. i have created comment feature similar with [here](https://scotch.io/@tomiiide/how-to-create-a-comment-system-with-laravel-53-and-vuejs), but due to certain circumstances i have to improvise it. i use vue component but it couldn't access method inside my vue. if user has already post comment, any user may be able to reply that particular comment. however, i received vue warn "Property or method 'replyComment' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". can anyone help me please?

```js
Vue.component('reply-komen',{
        template:'#replykomen',
        props:{
            edit:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            },
            comment:{
                type:Object,
                default(){
                    return {
                        title: '',
                        body: '',
                        id: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
            replyComment: function(comment_id){
                console.log(comment.id);
                var id={{$complaint->id}};
                var users={{Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id}};
                const item=this.$refs.balaskomen;
                const idkomen=item.dataset.id;
                console.log(idkomen);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/api/complaint/comment',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{
                        'users':users,
                        'id':id,
                        'comment':this.comment
                    },
                    success:function (response) {
                        komen2.comment.body= '';
                        komen2.fetchComments();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });

    var komen2=new Vue({
        el: '#kalas',
        data:{
            currentView:'',
            edit:false,
            comments:[],
            comment: {
                title:'',
                body: '',
                id: '',
            }
        },

        created: function(){
            this.fetchComments();
            this.createComment();
            this.editComment();
            this.deleteComment();
            this.showComment();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchComments: function(){
                var id={{$complaint->id}};
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/api/complaint/getcomments',
                    type:"GET",
                    data:{
                      'id':id
                    },
                    success:function (response) {
                        komen2.comments = response;
                    }
                })
            },

            createComment: function(){
                var id={{$complaint->id}};
                var users={{Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id}};
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/api/complaint/comment',
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{
                        'users':users,
                        'id':id,
                      'comment':this.comment
                    },
                    success:function (response) {
                        komen2.comment.body= '';
                        komen2.fetchComments();
                    }
                })
            },

            editComment: function(comment_id){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/api/complaint/'+window.Laravel.post_id+'/comment'+comment_id,
                    type:"PATCH",
                    data:{
                        'comment':this.comment
                    },
                    success:function (response) {
                        komen2.comment.body= '';
                        komen2.comment.id= '';
                        komen2.fetchComments();
                        komen2.edit = false;
                    }
                })
            },

            deleteComment: function(comment_id){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/api/complaint/'+window.Laravel.post_id+'/comment'+comment_id,
                    type:"DELETE",
                    success:function (response) {
                        komen2.comment.body= '';
                        komen2.fetchComments();
                    }
                })
            },

            showComment: function(comment_id){
                for (var i = 0; i < this.comments.length; i++) {
                    if (this.comments[i].id == comment_id) {
                        this.comment.body = this.comments[i].body;
                        this.comment.id = this.comments[i].id;
                        this.edit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kalas">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Add Comment</h4>
        <form action="" @submit.prevent="edit ? editComment(comment.id) : createComment()">
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea name="body" v-model="comment.body" ref="textarea"  class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-show="!edit">Add Comment</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-show="edit">Edit Comment</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <ul class="list-group" v-for="comment in comments">
            {{--<li class="list-group-item" v-for="comment in comments">--}}
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control">@{{comment.body}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group" ref="balaskomen" v-bind:id="comment.id">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="currentView='reply-komen'">Reply</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click=" deleteComment(comment.id)">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            {{--</li>--}}
        </ul>
        <div class="container balas" >
            <component :is="currentView"></component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<template id="replykomen" >
    <form action="" @submit.prevent="replyComment(comment.id)">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea name="body" v-model="comment.body" ref="textarea"  class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-show="!edit">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replyComment` is defined in the second Vue instance (`#kalas`), but referenced in the first instance's template (`#replykomen`). Move/copy the method to the first Vue instance's methods to resolve the error.

Comment: thanks man you really great. i'd spend so much time just to figure this thing out.

Comment: @Mace No problem :)

Comment: can i ask you one more question? perhaps via twitter handle or skype?

Comment: Sure. @tonytrinh but best to ask on stackoverflow so that others could answer as well, especially if I’m not available or don’t know the answer.

Comment: i've edited the code as per your suggestion. it runs perfectly. now i actually tried to get comment.id of the comments that the user decided to reply, but it seems it is not passed into the components. i'd edited the props but alas nothing changes also. help me tony :'(

Comment: Can you create a new question that explains the problem with code?